# Share point 2013 search is not working on sub-site

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have root site and its sub-sites. I have enable search from Central Administrator. when I search any document (eg. test.doc) I don't get in search result but If I search anything other than that(eg. "home" as text) it work perfectly fine. On root site, I don't get such problem.

So, I am trying to know the reason why I can't search any document while search works perfectly fine for any text.

Hope I explain my problem very well.
Please let me know for further explanation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have configure your search setting and see the below link that helps you.
http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2013/09/03/how-to-change-the-way-search-results-are-displayed-in-sharepoint-server-2013.aspx